# The degree of the hypersurface of pfaffian cubic fourfolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\Pi:=\mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathbb{P}^5,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(3)))$ be the space of cubic fourfolds in $\mathbb{P}^5$. It is well-known that those cubics which are *pfaffian*, i.e. defined by the pfaffian of a 6-by-6 skew-symmetric 
matrix of linear forms, form a hypersurface in $\Pi$. Does anyone know the degree of that hypersurface?

Comment: You are looking for the degree of $\mathcal{C}_{14}$ in Hasset's notation, right?

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Example 3, p. 319 of

Li, Zhiyuan; Zhang, Letao: [*Modular forms and special cubic fourfolds*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2013.06.003), Adv. Math. **245**, 315-326 (2013). [ZBL1290.11077](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1290.11077),

the degree of $\mathcal{C}_{14}$ should be 915678.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! I was totally unaware of that paper.

Answer (score 1):

Just a remark: the Pfaffian locus is not quite the $\mathcal{C}_{14}$ divisor, but rather a constructible dense subset of $\mathcal{C}_{14}$, see

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-018-1707-7.

The divisor $\mathcal{C}_{14}$ is rather the locus of cubic fourfolds containing a quartic rational normal scroll $T$ (or a deformation of such $T$ with $T\cdot H^2=4$ and $T\cdot T=10$).

Comment: Right. Of course the hypersurface I had in mind is the closure of the Pfaffian locus.